# php database to table display

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am in kind of fix with this issue: whether I should use a database query or array manipulation.

My database structure with some sample dummy data-

```
Name , description , location , datefrom , dateto
1    , description1 , d1,        date1,     date 2
1    , description2 , d2,        date1,     date 2
2    , description3 , d3,        date1,     date 2
2    , description4 , d3,        date1,     date 2
1    , description5 , d1,        date1,     date 2
```

Out put required.

Problem - SQL Query to select distinct name from Database
          SQl QUERY to GET ARRAY of all distinct names

ARRAY FORMAT:

```
      array (
             [0] = array(
                        [id] => 1,
                        [name] => dummyname,
                        [description] => description1
                        [location] => d1
                        )
             [1] = array(
                        [id] => 2,
                        [name] => dummyname,
                        [description] => description2
                        [location] => d2
                        )
             )
```

and so on...

Can share the code if you like - sorry its a bit confusing...let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, this is very broad. What exactly are you stuck with?

Comment: For a given ID which description and location do you want? First, Last all? Also what db are you using?

Comment: You should use a Database only if you need persistent data...

Answer (score 0):

> Problem - SQL Query to select distinct name from Database SQl QUERY to GET ARRAY of all distinct names

Not entirely sure what you mean by this, however, this is my interpretation;

View SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96f33/1

As you see, the table has two values the same ('John'), however, `SELECT DISTINCT` only returns one.

Then, execute this logic in PHP;

```
<?php
/*
 * Return all distinct values (`name`) from a table
 * Store within an array

 * For demo purposes only, I shall use inferior MySQL - MySQLi is preferred.
 */

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT username FROM users";
//Run the query
$db = mysql_query($sql);
//Create an array to store the returned values
$return = array();
//Loop through the results
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($db)) {
    //Store them in the array
    $return[] = $r['username'];
}

print_r($return);
?>
```

For development (and code practice) refrain from using mysql. Adopt PDO or MySQLi :)
I hope that helps you, as it was my interpretation of a broad question/request